# Как избавиться от "property 'companies' implicitly has an 'any[]' "

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

```
Здравствуйте.

Мне необходимо передать в стейт массив из объектов. И все работает, за исключением ошибки типизации, которую выдает typescript ('companies' неявно приведен к типу 'any'). Как правильно описать 'companies', если результат запроса массив объектов вида:
{ id: 1,
  name: "Some Company",
  address: "Some City",
  phone: 322323222}
```

Код компонента:

```
export default class Companies extends React.Component {

state = {
    companies:[]
}

componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/organization`)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data) {
                this.setState({companies: res.data});
            } else {
                throw 'error';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};

render() {

    const isLogged = store.getState();

    if (isLogged) return (

        <div>
            Вход выполнен
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            Вход не выполнен
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

И если не сложно, напишите, что стоит почитать на русском по TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

```
interface ICompany {
id: number,
name: string,
address: string}

interface IAll {
companies: ICompany[]}

export default class Companies extends React.Component<IAll, {}> {
state: Readonly<IAll> = {
    companies: null
}

componentDidMount() {
Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/organization`)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data) {
            this.setState({companies: res.data});
        } else {
            throw 'error';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });};
```